# O que é Multi-Tenancy?

Tags: terminologia, arquitetura-de-software, multi-tenancy

- O que é Multi-Tenancy?
- Quais principais abordagens para implementá-lo?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> O que é Multi-Tenancy?

É a capacidade da aplicação suportar a execução de diversos usuários ou grupos de usuários que possuem alguma ligação e precisam do funcionamento dela de uma forma específica. Em geral cada um terá seus dados separados, configurações próprias, funcionam de forma independente, mas é uma aplicação só rodando. Em geral esse grupo de usuários, pode ser uma empresa que contratou um serviço de aplicação. Mas pode ser seu navegador que permite que vários usuários o usem de forma independente sem que o uso de um afete o outro.

Como o nome em inglês diz, você **arrenda** uma parte de uma infraestrutura para você. Outras partes da mesma infraestrutura ficam disponíveis para outras pessoas de forma isolada. O isolamento se dá pela forma como a aplicação foi desenvolvida.

O sistema operacional costuma funcionar assim, pelo menos em partes. Como nem tudo é perfeito como *multitenancy* existem soluções como o [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)). Bancos de dados funcionam assim.

Virtualização, nuvem, essas coisas não costumam ser consideradas multitenancy porque o isolamento é grande demais é quase como rodar em máquinas separadas. Mas principalmente há instâncias separadas, o isolamento não é feito pela aplicação em questão e sim por uma ferramenta externa.

Ela se contrapõe à aplicação rodar de forma totalmente isolada para vários usuários. Se você fizer instalações totalmente separadas, mesmo rodando na mesma máquina não é *multitenancy*.

Mas obviamente que nem precisa ser tudo na mesma máquina para ser *multitenancy*, desde que as diversas máquinas trabalhem com mais de um grupo de usuários isoladamente. O fato da aplicação ser distribuída nada tem a ver com o conceito de multi arrendamento.

Em geral existem bancos de dados diferentes (não importa o que seja esse DB, se é SQL, se são arquivos e diretórios, registro do Windows, etc.) para cada usuário/grupo e código sabe lidar com isso. Não pode ter algo que faça globalmente na máquina, porque a máquina não é de apenas um usuário.

Se a aplicação não for desenhada para trabalhar dessa forma provavelmente haverá confusão. Em geral isso exige um pouco mais de complexidade no desenvolvimento porque tudo precisa ser configurável de acordo com o "cliente" que está arrendando sem atrapalhar os demais, mas facilita a implantação e manutenção física do ambiente, embora atualizações podem ser mais problemáticas.

A manutenção do desenvolvimento precisa ser feita com um pouco mais de cuidado porque várias situações são possíveis, principalmente quando algo incompatível é feito. Piora quando os "clientes" possuem muita flexibilidade e podem personalizar demais algumas coisas.

> Quais principais abordagens para implementá-lo?

Não sei se consigo responder isso, a não ser dizendo o óbvio, que todos os recursos precisam poder ser acessados conforme alguma informação que remete a qual cliente está operando naquele momento. Essa decisão de pegar os dados de qual lugar pode ser tomada baseada no *login* efetuando, uma configuração em algum lugar, uma chave, o local de onde vem o acesso, ou mesmo o domínio de internet que está acessando, só para citar algumas.

Se for usar um banco de dados tradicional, pode ser que todos os "clientes" estejam em uma mesma base de dados e tenha uma chave para diferenciar a quem pertence aquela linha. Ou pode ter bases de dados diferentes e completamente isoladas, o que pode dar mais possibilidades de personalização de cada um.

As abordagens são tantas e algumas tão específicas para o tipo de aplicação que ficaria difícil citar. Eu citei exemplos de aplicação que muita gente não percebe que é *multitenancy*, cada um tem sua abordagem, quem entende o funcionamento deles deve perceber como cada um funciona.

O sistema que usa isto é multi-tenant.

Answer (score 10):

De forma resumida multi-tenancy é quando você tem um sistema que aceita varios usuário, onde cada usuário utiliza o sistema de forma isolada.

Um exemplo é o [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com) onde cada usuário tem o seu blog independe e isolado dos outros blogs. Diferente do Facebook, onde todos os usuários coexistem no mesmo ambiente.