# Estrutura do Banco de Dados - Php e Mysql - Marketplace

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

boa noite, tenho um sistema de lojas. Um banco de dados em MySQL para todas, estou re-estruturando, porém estou com um dilema para resolver.

O cadastro dos clientes! Pois como tenho apenas um banco, tenho apenas um cadastro único para cada cliente. Mas o cliente pode comprar na Loja X e na Loja Y, o que possivelmente poderia ser um cadastro diferente para cada loja.

Qual o melhor cenário?

- Criar uma base de dados para cada loja?
- Uma base de dados porém coleções/tabelas de clientes para cada loja?

Há possibilidade no futuro de unificar todas as lojas em um único site/app, dessa forma se tiver várias bases de dados não poderia dificultar essa integração?

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está perguntando é se deve escolher *multi-tenancy* ou não. É isso que deve procurar. E [já respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179757/101) sobre ele.

Não temos como responder para você qual é o melhor cenário para seu caso. Há vantagens e desvantagens para cada caso e mesmo que soubéssemos a sua arquitetura ainda não podemos afirmar sem saber o volume real que irá lidar, o que interfere na decisão. E quando se pensa em arquitetura deveria considerar antes o que fazer e depois escolher a tecnologia que vai usar, pode ser que a que escolheu não seja a mais adequada para algum dos cenários.

Sempre há possibilidade de mudar, dá um pouco de trabalho, mas é possível, se acha que pode ocorrer isto, planeje pensando nisso para facilitar a migração.

Particularmente se vai manter tudo junto ou separado não importa tanto quando se fala do cadastro de clientes, ambos são possíveis, pode estar junto fisicamente mas separados logicamente, mas se quer compartilhar os mesmos clientes para todas as lojas precisa se perguntar se eles são de todas as lojas. É uma empresa só com várias lojas? Me parece fazer sentido compartilhar, aí é questão de fazer de forma adequada. Cada loja é uma empresa diferente? Tem zero sentido em compartilhar os clientes. Mas é uma decisão de negócios não de arquitetura.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @JeffersonFernandes legal, agora você também pode votar em tudo que achar legal no site.