# Estruturando um Banco de Dados SaaS

Tags: banco-de-dados, aplicação-web

Bom, estou estudando um pouco sobre aplicações `.NET` como **Serviço** e não como Produto, a fim de que seja feita uma **assinatura mensal** do cliente pelo uso da aplicação.

Contando que a base de dados vai ser única e a hospedagem é toda por minha responsabilidade, esta seria a maneira correta de estruturar o **banco de dados**?

Comment: Eu já tive uma dúvida parecida a um tempo atrás, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174873/estrutura-web-api-para-v%C3%A1rios-clientes, mais vou escrever uma resposta mais atual e completa para esta questão. Visto que muita coisa mudou de lá pra cá.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa é uma questão que gera bastante discussão, visto que muitos fatores devem ser avaliados. ***Minha intenção com esta resposta não é te falar "faça isso e desta forma" e sim te indicar possíveis caminhos para que você possa se aprofundar e avaliar o que melhor lhe atende.***

Há um tempo atrás fiz uma [pergunta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174873/estrutura-web-api-para-v%C3%A1rios-clientes) e obtive uma resposta muito interessante que me ajudou a me guiar num projeto que estava fazendo. Com base nesta pergunta e a resposta nela contida, estudei vários conceitos que me levaram a tomar decisões de arquitetura para o projeto em questão, abaixo um resumo do que entendi da resposta e mais algumas informações que possam lhe ser úteis mais [dá uma conferida na pergunta original pra enriquecer o debate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174873/estrutura-web-api-para-v%C3%A1rios-clientes).

Basicamente, deve-se montar uma estratégia para atacar dois pontos principais, a arquitetura dos dados e a arquitetura da aplicação.

**Arquitetura dos dados**

A arquitetura dos dados é primordial, escolhas erradas neste ponto, podem render um montante considerável de trabalho extra quando a aplicação estiver em produção. E quando estamos pensando em uma solução Saas é primordial termos isolamento dos dados entre clientes, entre usuários e entre ambientes (beta, produção).

Existem duas estratégias basicamente:

1. **Bancos de dados individuais por cliente:** Nesta abordagem, cada cliente tem o seu banco de dados separado, garantindo assim o isolamento das informações. Apesar de ser o caminho mais lógico, devemos avaliar a questão do custo de manutenção da estrutura em caso de migrações.
2. **Um Banco de dados para compartilhado para todos os clientes:** Nesta abordagem temos apenas um banco de dados que contém as informações de todos os clientes e a separação dos dados se dá por meio de estratégias de segregação das informações por cliente e por usuário. Legal, neste caso mantemos apenas uma instância de banco de dados e quando for necessário realizar alguma manutenção no banco o custo de manutenção será bem mais barato, visto que faremos o processo uma só vez. Em contrapartida, o nosso custo de banco de dados e processamento será muito maior e poderemos enfrentar problemas de limitação de memória, IOPs (no caso de bancos na núvem).

Para as duas abordagens você deve preparar a sua aplicação/API para trabalhar da forma desejada e para isso existem inúmeras estratégias que não vem ao caso mostrar aqui.

**Arquitetura de aplicação**

Apesar de não ser o foco da pergunta, a arquitetura da aplicação é extremamente importante de ser citada e é um fator determinante quando vamos trabalhar com multitenancy.

A arquitetura da aplicação deve permitir que ela seja antes de tudo resiliente e escalável. Não adianta termos uma estratégia bem definida para trabalhar com o banco de dados se nossa aplicação não tem essas duas caracteristicas.

Pense comigo, se tivermos apenas uma instância de nossa aplicação rodando e recebendo tráfego de todos os clientes, uma hora ou outra o servidor vai abrir o bico, aí já viu né... sai ferrando tudo, causando indisponibilidade e travando a aplicação.

Por isso é importante pensar bem na arquitetura da aplicação, na minha experiência com a aplicação acima citada eu enfrentei diversos problemas.

Eu criei a aplicação bem estruturada para que possibilitasse trabalhar com qualquer uma das duas estratégias de banco de dados, mais a minha API era um grande monolito e quando algo consumia um processamento considerável isso impactava os outros usuários aumentando o tempo de resposta e gargalando minha aplicação, sem contar nos custos de processamento da núvem que iam lá em cima em momentos de pico.

Hoje temos diversas técnicas e conceitos que podem nos auxiliar a criar aplicações resilientes e escaláveis:

- Microsserviços para garantir isolamento e evitar que um problema específico impacte todos os clientes;
- Arquitetura CQRS para separação entre estratégias de Read e Write;
- Estratégias de cache para reduzir o acesso ao banco de dados;
- Podemos usar o conceito de mensageria usando uma fila para armazenar os dados antes da persistência dos dados;
- Podemos usar o conceito de Api Gateway e API Management para gerenciar microsserviços com eficiência.

> Como dito no início, é um assunto amplo e que pode gerar muita
>   discussão, a chave é estudar e ver o que melhor se aplica a sua
>   necessidade. Abaixo vou repassar alguns links legais que podem lhe
>   ajudar a estudar melhores soluções:

[Série Desmitificando multitenancy](https://medium.com/sejakino/desmitificando-multitenancy-parte-1-introducao-e0e0f2169649)

[O que é multitenancy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179757/o-que-%C3%A9-multi-tenancy)

[Wikipédia (é claro, não poderia faltar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

[Mensageria não é um bicho de sete cabeças](https://imasters.com.br/devsecops/mensageria-nao-e-um-bicho-de-7-cabecas)

[Introdução à mensageria](https://www.concrete.com.br/2012/01/23/introducao-a-mensageria/)

[CQRS o que é? e onde aplicar?](https://www.eduardopires.net.br/2016/07/cqrs-o-que-e-onde-aplicar/)

[API Gateway governando a arquitetura de microsserviços](https://sensedia.com/blog/apis/api-gateway-governando-a-arquitetura-de-microservices/)

Espero ter te ajudado a definir algo mais concreto.

Comment: Obrigado Júlio! Abriu um pouco minha mente em relação a isso!